# Infinispan doesn't replicate cache entity remove to non-coordinator node

Tags: java, infinispan, infinispan-9

**Environment**

1. Infinispan 9.4.18 embedded
2. 3 nodes cache in replicated mode
3. RocksDB store (or other, doesn't matter)

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create TCP-based cluster
2. Create cache
3. Add Entity to cache
4. Check that entity is stored on each node
5. Stop non-coordinator node
6. Remove Entity from cache on coordinator
7. Check that Entity is removed on running nodes
8. Start previously stopped non-coordinator node
9. Check that Entity is present on restarted node but is absent on remaining nodes. But expected behavior is to replicate removing to restarted node too.

**Questions**
1. Is this behavior OK? 
2. Can I change it to indicated as expected? 
3. And how if so?

Answer (score 0):

Infinispan does not replicate removals to a restarted node. The workaround is to remove all the entries in the restarted node's stores before starting, by configuring the store with [`purge="true"`](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/10.1/configdocs/infinispan-cachestore-rocksdb-config-10.1.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer! But it is not useful for me. Because cluster with this setting can't survive simultaneous restart of all nodes.

Comment: Yes, removing all the data on cluster restart is a big limitation. Unfortunately there's no other built-in option, you'll have to remove the store data from an external script before restarting the node.

Comment: Or implement other solution. Do not remove removed records but mark them as removed. And schedule a task that will periodically remove such marked records on each node. Yes, it will make impact on range read but will repair consistency problem.